Error on yfinance download of list of SP500 tickers
does anybody why this part of script I used till a few weeks ago has stopped working?
pip install yahoo_fin

import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import yfinance as yf
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
import datetime as dt
import warnings
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tickers = si.tickers_sp500() 

Usually I got the correct list of tickers, now I only get a list of '-' ... does anybody know why?

This is not a python issue per se. You should contact the author(s) of yahoo_fin which appears to be broken

The yahoo_fin module is broken.
The tickers_sp500 function relies on being able to interpret an HTML page hosted at "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
This may have been valid at some point in the past. It isn't now. The page layout has probably changed.
You can review the code in the yahoo_fin distribution - specifically, stock_info.py
